# Calculate Datetime MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need an SQL Command that do this.
My source data is:

> Date;W1
>
> 2014-05-02 03:00:10;2500
> 2014-05-02 03:00:11;2800
> 2014-05-02 03:00:12;2900
> 2014-05-02 03:00:13;1000
> 2014-05-02 03:00:14;1000
> 2014-05-02 05:00:10;1000
> 2014-05-02 05:00:11;1000
> 2014-05-02 05:00:12;1000
> 2014-05-02 05:00:13;1000
> 2014-05-02 05:00:14;1000
> 2014-05-02 08:00:10;3000
> 2014-05-02 08:00:11;2500
> 2014-05-02 08:00:12;2000
> 2014-05-02 08:00:13;2500
> 2014-05-02 08:00:14;2800

As result I want now the date difference where W1 is higher then 2000

Should be like:

> 2014-05-02 03:00:10 -> 2014-05-02 03:00:12
> 2014-05-02 08:00:10 -> 2014-05-02 03:00:14

I know I could do that with php but is there a methode to do it with a sql command?

Thanks for help

Edit 1:
Or that I get at least something like this:

> 2014-05-02 03:00:10
> 2014-05-02 03:00:12
> 2014-05-02 08:00:10
> 2014-05-02 03:00:14

Every time when more then 1 second is between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would be simple if you group the rows by date and hours except minutes and then count the different dates if there exists more than one,this satisfies the  seconds difference condition and thus you can use `min/max` to get the dates from `'%Y-%m-%d %H'` group

```
SELECT 
MIN(`Date`) `min_date`,
MAX(`Date`) `max_date`,
CONCAT(MIN(`Date`)  ,'->',MAX(`Date`) ) `concatenated`,
COUNT(DISTINCT `Date`) `different_dates`
FROM t
WHERE `W1` > 2000
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`Date`,'%Y-%m-%d %H')
HAVING different_dates >1
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d42085/2)

Comment: That won't give an entry between 03:00:12 and 08:00:10, and it will give seperate entries when you have Data at 08:00:59 and 08:01:10

Comment: when you add  ('2014-05-02 05:00:58', 2300), ('2014-05-02 05:01:02', 2300), then you get no data at all for 05:00.

Comment: @flaschenpost see my updated answer now group by will look for `'%Y-%m-%d %H'` format

Comment: Echoing the comments from @flaschenpost: This approach has the potential to (incorrectly) identify a single range within an hour (or whatever period) when there are multiple individual ranges within the hour. That is, when the value of w1 goes above and drops below 2000 several times within an hour. (This result may be suitable for the OP, but I wanted to point that out, for future readers, concerned with a more general case.)

Comment: Thats true and a problem for me. I'm using this in a second data table from a complete day (60*60*24). And there I get:
2014-05-02 19:04:30 -> 2014-05-02 19:22:32 324
2014-05-02 20:20:59 -> 2014-05-02 20:43:41 170

Answer (score 0):

I think `create table w1data (atime DATETIME, value int)` and a `LOAD DATA INFILE` is quite easy.

After that you have a table which can be filtered by

```
select * from w1data where value > 2000
```

which is not what you want, but a good start.

Now you want to compare two different rows of a select, which needs a kond of a trick:

```
set @lastrow = NULL;
select (if(@lastrow is NULL, NULL, unix_timestamp(atime) - unix_timestamp(@lastrow)) as diff_seconds, @lastrow := atime as dummy
from (select distinct atime from w1data where value > 2000 order by atime)
;
```

EDIT: 
If you want the times instead of the seconds, just use (EDIT2: Typo, and restricted word `when` replaced) (EDIT3: inner select needs an alias of course)

```
set @lastrow = NULL;
select concat(@lastrow, " -> ", atime) as length, (@lastrow := atime) as dummy
from (select distinct atime from w1data where value > 2000 order by atime) as dat_sel
;
```

Comment: When I run this I'm getting:
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as length, (@lastrow := Datum) as dummy from (select distinct Datum from data w' at line 1

Comment: @user3308194: sorry, I had have restricted word. I'm used not to use english column names, so I was not aware of a good column name for the datetime.

Comment: corrected as http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10b403/19/1, 'Start' is better than NULL. I am really sorry, I should definitely test before writing nonsense... But the core is simple, really: just never use that trick with a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to to get the specified result,

```
SELECT CONCAT(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.state,'#',2),'#',-1)
       ,' -> ',
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.state,'#',3),'#',-1)
       ) AS `r`
  FROM ( SELECT IF(@state+0,
                  IF(w1>2000, NULL, CONCAT(@state := 0,'#', @start, '#', @prev_dt , '#')),
                  IF(w1>2000, CONCAT(@state := 1,'#',@start := dt,'#'), NULL)
                ) AS state
              , @prev_dt := m.dt AS dt
           FROM mydata m
          CROSS
           JOIN (SELECT @start := '', @prev_dt := '', @state := '0') i
          ORDER BY m.dt, m.w1 
       ) t
 WHERE t.state LIKE '0#%'
   AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.state,'#',3),'#',-1) 
     > SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.state,'#',2),'#',-1)
```

This uses MySQL user defined variables to "save" values from previous rows. The inline view query (aliased as t) does the work of checking the value of w1, and determining whether a range has started   or ended.

The outer query picks up only the rows where a range has been marked as "ended". (This only returns ranges that have ended, that is, if the last row has a value of w1>2000, the range won't be marked as ended yet, and the range containing that row will be omitted.

Adding an extra "trailing" record (i.e. `"UNION ALL SELECT MAX(n.dt+INTERVAL 1 SECOND AS dt, 0 AS w1 FROM mydata n"` would address that. Or, the list could be processed in reverse order, from the latest date back to the earliest date, reversing the checks, and then an unstarted "earliest" range would be omitted.)

This approach will work for "ranges" of any length, that span a few seconds, or many hours or days (as long as the range is ended).

Setup test case:

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (dt DATETIME, w1 INT UNSIGNED) ENGINE=MYISAM;

CREATE INDEX mydata_IX1 ON mydata (dt, w1);

INSERT INTO mydata (dt, w1) VALUES
('2014-05-02 03:00:10','2500')
,('2014-05-02 03:00:11','2800')
,('2014-05-02 03:00:12','2900')
,('2014-05-02 03:00:13','1000')
,('2014-05-02 03:00:14','1000')
,('2014-05-02 05:00:10','1000')
,('2014-05-02 05:00:11','1000')
,('2014-05-02 05:00:12','1000')
,('2014-05-02 05:00:13','1000')
,('2014-05-02 05:00:14','1000')
,('2014-05-02 08:00:10','3000')
,('2014-05-02 08:00:11','2500')
,('2014-05-02 08:00:12','2000')
,('2014-05-02 08:00:13','2500')
,('2014-05-02 08:00:14','2800');
```

Comment: Why and what are you doing here: "CREATE INDEX mydata_IX1 ON mydata (dt, w1);" ?